# How to Show Complex Error Page on Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-compute-engine

I have written an ASP.NET MVC App that is running on a Google Compute Engine. The app is getting a 500 Error on the main Index page that does not occur when running on my local machine.

I am trying to get the complex error page to show from the server, as it is much easier to view them on the web page for hotfixing issues than to delve into the Google Cloud Console to retrieve them. I do not want custom errors, just the same amount of depth that gets shown when running on my local machine.

I have tried:

- Removing the existing HTTP Global Filter
- Adding `<customErrors
  mode="Off"/><compilation debug="true"/>` to my System.Web in
  Web.config
- Adding `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" /><asp
  scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>` to my System.WebServer in
  Web.config
- Publishing as debug

Ideas? I'm sure theres a publish setting I'm missing somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a constructor to the page controller finally provided the detailed error log. If you have taken all of the steps above to get the log, and it still has yet to show, ensure there are constructors for all view controllers involved. Even if the constructor is blank.

I still need to delve into my particular crash issue, but at least I can get an idea where to start.